# Is it possible to search for a string and replace it with another string in the title tag of multiple mp3 files?

Tags: regular-expression, mp3, file-metadata

I would like to

1. search for "ytversion",
2. replace it with "mqversion"
3. in the title tag

of multiple mp3 files. I would like this process not edit/delete any other parts of the metadata content.

Is this possible? If yes, which tools would I have to use?

1. I know I can search for a certain string in the metadata of multiple mp3 files. This is possible in EasyTag.
2. However, how can I replace that particular string with another string for the pre-defined metadata field (the title field in the example above)?

I do not need to use EasyTag, it's just what I had installed at some point.

I suppose the answer to my question relies on regular expressions which I would definitely be ok with to use. It just that I do not know of any program (whether it has to be used in the CLI or has a GUI) that is capable to employ them or actually implements them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what this string is and what it should be replaced with. There are dozens of tools that can manipulate mp3 tags, but we can't help you unless you give a specific example we can test.

Comment: @terdon I edited the post.

Comment: Thanks, but where would this string be? In the genre tag? The title? The artist? All you need to do is loop over your files, print the relevant information, test if the string is there and then issue a command to change the tag. But we can only help you do this if we know what tag we're talking about so we can know what command would need to be issued.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for your clarifying questions. I edited the post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `id3v2` tool, which should be in the repositories for your operating system (note that this solution assumes GNU `grep`, the default if you are running Linux):

```bsh
## Iterate over all file/dir names ending in mp3
for file in /path/to/dir/with/mp3/files/*mp3; do 
    ## read the title and save in the variable $title
    title=$(id3v2 -l "$file" | grep -oP '^(Title\s*|TIT2\s*.*\)):\K(.*?)(?=Artist:)'); 
    ## check if this title matches ytversion
    if [[ "$title" =~ "ytversion" ]]; then 
        ## If it does, replace ytversion with mqversion and 
        ## save in the new variable $newTitle
        newTitle=$(sed 's/ytversion/mqversion/g' <<<"$title") 
        ## Set the tite tag for this file to the value in $newTitle
        id3v2 -t "$newTitle" "$file" 
    fi
done
```

This si slightly complicated because the `id3v2` tool prints the title and artist on the same line:

```
$ id3v2 -l foo.mp3 
id3v1 tag info for foo.mp3:
Title  : : title with mqversion string   Artist:                               
Album  :                                 Year:     , Genre: Unknown (255)
Comment:                                 Track: 0
id3v2 tag info for foo.mp3:
TENC (Encoded by): iTunes v7.0
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): : title with mqversion string
```

The `-o` flag tells `grep` to only print the matching portion of a line, and the `-P` enables PCRE regular expressions. The regex is searching for either a line starting with `Title` followed by 0 or more whitespace characters and then an `:` (`^Title\s*:`) or a line starting with `TIT2`, and then having a `):` (`^TIT2\s*.*\)`). Everything matched up to that point is then discarded by the `\K`. it then searches for the shortest string of characters (`.*?`) followed by  `Artist:`.(`(?=Artist:)`; this is called a [positive lookahead](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php) and matches the string you are looking for without having it count in the match, so it isn't printed by `grep`).

Comment: Thank your for your reply. As far as I can tell, this does not seem to work as the line with `"$title" =~ "ytversion"` checks if the string is equal to "ytversion". It should check if it contains "ytversion".

Comment: ... uh. Also: `$ id3v2 -l Chloe\ Wilson\ feat.\ NIEMY\ \&\ Ivan\ Gough\ -\ 200\ Years\ \(Ivan\ Gough\ \&\ Marcus\ Santoro\ Extended\ Remix\)\ \(ytversion\).mp3` gives me: 
`id3v2 tag info for Chloe Wilson feat. NIEMY & Ivan Gough - 200 Years (Ivan Gough & Marcus Santoro Extended Remix) (ytversion).mp3:
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): 200 Years (Ivan Gough & Marcus Santoro Extended Remix) (ytversion)`. => At the beginning of the line, there is "TIT2" apparently.

Comment: @henry no, `=~` checks for a match. Try `[[ "foo" =~ "o" ]] && echo yes || echo no` and `[[ "foo" =~ "b" ]] && echo yes || echo no`. As for the `TIT2` well, that's why you need to give specific examples! Anyway, try the updated answer.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator if you want that comment to be read by the OP, you need to `@` ping them. Otherwise, I'm the only one who gets notified since I wrote the answer.

Comment: I edited the script because I at some point I finally realized that all tags were version 2. This is the version I used: https://pastebin.com/vk6pBgCG But I am marking your post as solved anyway, because you did 80% of the leg work, I just had to fiddle in the rest (once I realized I need `-E` when I want to use regex with sed... ). I'd appreciate it if you list 2 versions, 1 for id3v1 and 1 for id3v2. As I understand, employing the positive lookahead is not possible for v2.

Comment: @henry the regexes have nothing to do with the version of the tags used. And you don't need `-E` to use regexes with `sed`, only if you want _extended_ regexes.